# What is this ? This is right next to our door chime

Tags: electrical

I'm trying to figure out what this is. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Anyway of seeing what is behind it?  Looks like a bad speaker cover or a type of vent cover.

Comment: @crip659 "bad speaker cover" indeed!!!

Answer (score 11):

This is an indoor alarm siren for a home security system:

[Honeywell WAVE-2 Two Tone Siren](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0006BCCAE)

Comment: Wow... there must be some specific domain knowledge there to have ID'd that so quickly!

Comment: @FreeMan, Yea, I had a very similar one in a previous house, and coincidentally, it was also right next to the doorbell.  There was also an "outdoor" siren in the attic close to the doorbell transformer.  I guess just convenience.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Yep, almost certainly convenience. These things tend to be low voltage DC devices just like doorbells and thermostats, and it’s probably using the same power source as the doorbell.